# PHP converting an SVG to PNG WITHOUT ImageMagick

Tags: php, windows, svg, imagemagick, png

I need to convert SVG XML to a PNG using PHP without anything like ImageMagick that requires installation on the server.  I know this has been asked once before, but there wasn't an answer that fits this.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: PHP has **NO** native image handling capabilities. Unless you want to write your own rasterizer to convert svg vector -> png rasters, you're stuck with external libraries, e.g. imagick

Comment: You would have to parse the XML and convert it to a png. Therefore you could begin to parse the SVG ( [loop through xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226736/loop-through-svg-elements-with-php)) and write a PNG. I think you'd be better off, if   you would create an external webservice that accepts SVG and serves PNG with imagemagick, inkscape or rsvg.

Comment: @Marc B - GD? GD2?  Sure, neither do SVG - but no native graphics?  Not true.

Comment: @michael: that's not "native". It's an optional module that does tend to be available in most places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not already have IMagick or MagicWand built in PHP then there is nearly no chance. You could write a SVG parser and PNG writer by your own what would be no fun - i promise.